# Let $a,b,c,d$ be distinct integers such that the equation $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)-9=0$ has an integer root $r$,then find the value of $a+b+c+d-4r.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

Let $a,b,c,d$ be distinct integers such that the equation $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)-9=0$ has an integer root $r$,then find the value of $a+b+c+d-4r.$

---

As $r$ is the integer root of the equation $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)-9=0$,so $(r-a)(r-b)(r-c)(r-d)=9$
or $(a-r)(b-r)(c-r)(d-r)=9$
We need to find $(a-r)+(b-r)+(c-r)+(d-r)$ but i do not know how to find that.

Comment: Hint: everything's an integer, so the fundamental theorem of arithmetic applies.

Comment: Hint: how to express $9$ as a product of four distinct integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a,b,c$ and $d$ are distinct integers.

So $r-a,r-b,r-c$ and $r-d$ are all distinct integers.

Again, $9=3^2$

Hence the only possible factorisation: $$(r-a)(r-b)(r-c)(r-d)=3\cdot 3\cdot 1 \cdot 1$$ or 
$$(a-r)(r-b)(c-r)(r-d)=3\cdot 3\cdot 1 \cdot 1$$

So we have $a=r+3$, $b=r-3$, $c=r+1$, $d=r-1$.

Thus $\color{blue}{a+b+c+d-4r} = \color{red}{0}$

Comment: Why not $(a-r)(b-r)(c-r)(d-r)=3.3.1.1$ so that $a=r+3,b=r+3,c=r+1,d=r+1$, so that $a+b+c+d-4r=8$@Schrodingers Cat

Comment: I might be a bit picky, but any permutation of $a,b,c,d$ would also work, so what you mentioned isn't the only possibility.

Comment: @Brahmagupta a,b,c,d are distinct. But your choice makes a,b same. Check that.

Comment: @Wojowu I said only possible FACTORISATION, not permutation. You can go for any permutation like you said, but the factorisation of $9$ should be as I have done.

Comment: Yes,you are right.But by $AM-GM$ inequality minimum value of $a+b+c+d-4r=a-r+b-r+c-r+d-r$ is $4\sqrt3$@SchrodingersCat

Comment: @Brahmagupta Again check that a,b,c,d,r are all integers. How can you add and subtract integers and get something irrational?

Comment: I was refering to your second-to-last line. Of course it doesn't make a difference, I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @Wojowu Then its okay. As you said there can be many permutations, Mine is only one choice.

Comment: That means $AM-GM$ inequality is not applicable here.@SchrodingersCat

Comment: @Brahmagupta Yes.